# Obtener nameSpace de un nodo XML

Tags: xml

Como se obtiene el namespace del siguiente nodo.

```
<Stat Type="City">Bergamo</Stat>
```

cuando mande la salida a consola, solo debe aparecer el nombre de Bergamo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132231/getting-the-text-portion-of-a-node-using-php-simple-xml

Comment: Puedes checar esta información de lectura y escritura de XML en C# utilizando XmlDocument - Lectura: https://aprendetesto.blogspot.com/2018/07/lectura-de-archivos-xml-xmldocument.html - Escritura: https://aprendetesto.blogspot.com/2018/06/escritura-de-archivos-xml-xmldocument.html